# mysql connect (port,username,password)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect to mysql workbench using mysql_connect in php. The trouble is I get absolutely nothing not even an error with the die parameters. I think there is an issue with the values I put in for mysql_connect(hostname,username,password)? I have, I think tried everything including the following from the php manual:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());<?php
// we connect to example.com and port 3306
$link = mysql_connect('example.com:3306', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);

// we connect to localhost at port 3306
$link = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1:3306', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>

I'm sure it is something simple!?
```

Comment: What's with those 3 different connection? is it a bad copy/paste?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Hi guys , the code is a bad copy and paste job! I have tried the snippets of code which is syntactically correct on my interface, but get no response of either connected or error!

Answer (score 1):

You have a php tag within php tag (pasted multiple times?). It should throw an error, but it could be that your server is set so it doesn't show errors. That's why you see the blank page.

This is an example of what I mean:

```
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());<?php
```

You're already inside the php tag, you can't use another one. And there's no need to.

To enable error reporting the simplest way, put this at the top of your script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Start with a single connection, and make it work. And since you seem new to this, it might be a good idea to start with the right thing: drop the mysql_* functions, they are deprecated, and switch to mysqli or PDO.

Comment: error reporting should be enabled at the php.ini level, to catch compiler errors as well. there's far too many bugs that will kill a script long before it ever gets around to executing the `error_reporting()` call. it should never be disabled while debugging/developing in the first place anyways.

Comment: @MarcB Definitely! Didn't want to confuse OP more with modifying config at that level, but yeah, maybe I should have...

Comment: i just need a statement in php to  open a connection to the mysql workbench. Im using localhost. I have a password to open the mysql workbench. There is something wrong I think with the mysql_connect host,username,password attributes? As stated I get nothing!!